# How to get the manifests of a Docker image using HTTP API V2

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to get the image manifest of my private Docker image.

> GET /v2/name/manifests/reference

It is returning the header:
`Www-Authenticate →Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="repository:{username}:pull"`

So I made a request: `Www-Authenticate →Bearer realm="https://auth.docker.io/token",service="registry.docker.io",scope="repository:{username}:pull"` and I got the token.

I added it to the header `Authorization: Bearer {token}`.
But I still get 401 response.

Where do I put my username and password?

Answer (score 0):

See Docker's documentation for an explanation of auth:

https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-authenticate-with-the-v2-api

Specifically:

```sh
USERNAME=[[YOUR-USERNAME]]
PASSWORD=[[YOUR-PASSWORD]]
TOKEN=$(\
  curl \
  --silent \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username": "'${USERNAME}'", "password": "'${PASSWORD}'"}' \
  https://hub.docker.com/v2/users/login/ \
  | jq -r .token\
) & echo ${TOKEN}
```

This works for me for enumerating images and their tags.

I've been unable to query Docker's registry for manifests:

[How to get manifests using HTTP API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269256/how-to-get-manifests-using-http-api-v2)